# file type input value from table

Tags: php, html, file, input

I got editing page, where i can add images.

```
<div class="element">
<label for="attach">Attachments <span>(optional)</span></label>
<input type="file" id="img" name="img"/>
</div>
```

This is my input for adding images, my code is taking IMAGE NAME from it and inserting into row (thats how i call it $result['img']).

But when i'm editing the page again and saving it, the value in image row is deleting cause input got no value on it. How i can set value on it, so it dont delete on every edit.

edit.php

```
<?php
                        while($edit = mysql_fetch_array($query_edit)){
                            print "
                            <h2>".$edit['lang']." - ".$edit['title']."</h2>
                    <div class=\"entry\">
                        <div class=\"sep\"></div>
                    </div>
                            <form action=\"/admin/save\" method=\"post\" ENCTYPE=\"multipart/form-data\">
                            <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"name\">Page ID <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"id\" name=\"id\" value=".$edit['id']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"name\">Page title <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"title\" name=\"title\" value=".$edit['title']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"category\">Category <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"category\" name=\"category\" value=".$edit['category']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"category\">Sub-Category <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"sub_category\" name=\"sub_category\" value=".$edit['sub_category']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"category\">News-Category <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"news_category\" name=\"news_category\" value=".$edit['news_category']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"img\">Attachments <span>(optional)</span></label>
                        <input type=\"file\" id=\"img\" name=\"img\"/><br><br>
                        <img src='/views/admin/uploads/".$edit['img']."' title='no image'/>
                    </div>";
                    if($edit['short_content'] == ''){}
                    else {
                    print"
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"short-content\">Short content <span>(optional)</span></label>
                        <textarea name=\"short_content\" id=\"short_content\" class=\"textarea\" rows=\"10\">".$edit['short_content']."</textarea>
                    </div>
                    ";
                    }
                    print "
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"content\">Long content <span>(optional)</span></label>
                        <textarea name=\"long_content\" id=\"long_content\" class=\"textarea\" rows=\"10\">".$edit['content']."</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"date\">Date <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"date\" name=\"date\" class=\"text\" value=".$edit['date']." />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"element\">
                        <label for=\"language\">Language <span class=\"red\">(required)</span></label>
                        <input id=\"language\" name=\"language\" value=".$edit['lang']." class=\"text\" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"entry\">
                        <button type=\"submit\" id=\"button-save\" class=\"add button-save\">Save page</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                            ";
                        }
                    ?>
```

save.php

```
    <?php 
                    $id = $_POST['id'];
                    $category = $_POST['category'];
                    $sub_category = $_POST['sub_category'];
                    $news_category = $_POST['news_category'];
                    $title = $_POST['title'];
                    $short_content = $_POST['short_content'];
                    $long_content = $_POST['long_content'];
                    $date = $_POST['date'];
                    $lang = $_POST['language'];
                    //echo $id." ".$category." ".$title." ".$short_content." ".$lang." ".$date." ".$sub_category;

                    $errors = array();

                    if(empty($id)){
                        $errors[] = "Please fill ID";
                    }

                    if(empty($category)){
                        $errors[] = "Please fill Category";
                    }

                    if(empty($sub_category)){
                        $errors[] = "Please fill Sub-Category";
                    }


                    if(empty($news_category)){
                        $errors[] = "Please fill News-Category";
                    }


                    if(empty($title)){
                        $errors[] = "Please fill Title";
                    }

                    if(empty($date)){
                        $errors[] = "Please fill Date";
                    }

                    if(empty($lang)){
                        $errors[] = "Please fill Lang";
                    }

                    if(!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])){
                        $extension = end(explode(".",$_FILES['img']['name']));

                        $name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
                        $size = $_FILES['img']['size'];

                        if(file_exists("views/admin/uploads/".$name)){
                            $errors[] = "File with this name already exists!";
                        }

                        if($extension != "jpg" && $extension != "png" && $extension != "gif" && $extension != "JPG"){
                            $errors[] = "Unknown file format!";
                        }
                    }

                    if(count($errors)==0){
                        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `$category` SET `category`='$category',`sub_category`='$sub_category',`news_category`='$news_category',`title`='$title',`img`='$name',`short_content`='$short_content',`content`='$long_content',`date`='$date',`lang`='$lang' WHERE `id`='$id'");
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"views/admin/uploads/".$name);
                        echo "<h2 align=\"center\">Successfully updated!</h2>";
                    }
                    else{
                        print "<h3>Errors!</h3><ul><li>".join("</li><li>",$errors)."</li></ul>";
                    }
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<label for="img">`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have persistence of the image names with PHP. You need to use PHP to save each added image name to a database, preferably with an AJAX request.

#### Edit

First of all, you really need to sanitize your form inputs with PHP.

Second of  all, are you seeing the "Successfully updated" message, or are there errors that are not being shown?

Here's a [link to the PDO library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for MySQL database access with PHP.

Comment: Its just inserting name of image. Like - samsung-vc240-lcd-monitor.jpg, but when i edit it, it deletes old information in that row. So how i can give to file type input a value of that row?

Comment: As I said in my response, *you are not showing any PHP or Javascript code*, so we have no way of knowing what is going wrong with your code. The problem can't be debugged if we just have some HTML.

Comment: Everything is okay with code!!!!!!! When i edit the page, which got image and i save it WITHOUT selecting that image again, the value in image row (in database) is deleting, cause $edit['img'] is empty!! How can i set row value to file type input thats my problem?!